# PySerial: What is the difference between read() and readinto()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I've been using pySerial 3.4 in my code to extract data from serial port(an RFID chip reader/writer to be exact). I need to send a command to the reader and then read from the reader for results.

---

Basically, I am writing a 12 bytes command and then try to receive 24 bytes output.
My question is:  why does `port.read(24)` cannot work but `res = bytearray(24); port.readinto(res);`worked successfully?
Complete code attached:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5',9600,timeout=5,rtscts=True,inter_byte_timeout=5)

def compose_find(port):
    port.write(bytes.fromhex('555500000003020405'))
    port.flush()
    return port.read(12)[6] == 0

def compose_read(port,sec_loc=0,block_loc=0,key='F'*12):
    assert sec_loc in range(0,16),'sector location is from 0~15'
    assert block_loc in range(0,4),'block location is from 0~3'
    assert compose_find(port),'cannot read card!'

    sec_loc = '0'+str(hex(sec_loc))[2:]
    block_loc = '0'+str(hex(block_loc))[2:]
    command = '55 55 00 00 00 0E 03 07 00 00 {} {} 60 
        {}'.format(sec_loc,block_loc,key).replace(' ','')
    parity = str(hex(reduce(lambda x,y:x^y,bytes.fromhex(command))))[2:]
    if len(parity) == 1:  parity = '0'+parity
    command += parity
    print(command)
    port.write(bytes.fromhex(command))
    port.flush()
    res = bytearray(24)
    port.readinto(res)
    return res

compose_read(port=ser,sec_loc=8,block_loc=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readinto(buf)` reads UP TO `len(buf)` bytes and returns, while `read(num)` will **block** until `num` bytes are received. You have to specify `timeout` when opening the port, if you want `read()` to return even if there is not enough data available.

Comment: I did specifiy `timeout`  when opening port, and it just return `b''` even if `timeout` is set relatively long.

Comment: I have tested `readinto(bytearray(33333))` with the default `timeout = None` and saw it blocking until done, so both behave the same with respect to blocking.

Comment: @SamYu If it returns after a timeout, that still means you will only get as many bytes as were received. A `bytearray` of length 24 initially contains 24 null bytes. If `readinto` reads less, the remaining bytes just won't be overwritten.